# Is possible to run Selenium v4.1.5 with the Chromedriver v101.0.4951 on Debian v11.3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use selenium with some version of Chroium Web Driver. For that I have installed the [`webdriver_manager`](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/) on Debian (WSL 2 on Windows 10 Pro)

```
pip install webdriver_manager
```

I have used the lines recommended in the package `README` file for selenium 4. I have the version 4.1.5 installed

```
# selenium 4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.utils import ChromeType

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager(chrome_type=ChromeType.CHROMIUM).install()))
```

But I get this error. I have read that it may be that the selenium version is not compatible with this specific version of the chromedriver, but in the [quick reference guide of Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/install_drivers/), the download version is available  the [101.0.4951.41](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=101.0.4951.41/) version. I have installed the latest chrome version and chromedriver for Debian, which is the version 101.0.4951.64 right now. As the webdriver taken is from `/home/db/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/101.0.4951.41/chromedriver`, and not the installed in the system I don't know if it must match with the chrome version installed in the system. Do they have to match exactly?

This is the error once I run the python script:

```python
====== WebDriver manager ======
Current chromium version is 101.0.4951
Get LATEST chromedriver version for 101.0.4951 chromium
Driver [/home/db/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/101.0.4951.41/chromedriver] found in cache
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/path/to/python/project/webdriver.py", line 21, in <module>
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    File "/path/to/python/project/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 70, in __init__
        super(WebDriver, self).__init__(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
    File "/path/to/python/project/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
        RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
    File "/path/to/python/project/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 275, in __init__
        self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
    File "/path/to/python/project/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 365, in start_session
        response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
    File "/path/to/python/project/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 430, in execute
        self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    File "/path/to/python/project/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
        raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
```

Also, I got this other error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
```

And I had to add this code to fix it. But I don't think that will become a problem:

```python
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    service=Service(
        ChromeDriverManager(chrome_type=ChromeType.CHROMIUM).install(),
        # executable_path='/usr/bin/chromium'
    ),
    options=chrome_options
)
```

So I don't know if it's a version related problem or WSL problem. What else can I check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well finally, what solved my problem was to add the flags `--no-sandbox` and `--headless` to the options object

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")  # without this error > "chrome not found"
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")    # without this error > "chrome not found"
chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-using")
```

In spite of that it still give some random behaviour. I think it's due to my slow internet connection inside the WSL system. I was doing some research and I still didn't find any solution. I will post another question to check if anybody knows some workaround.